# Testing in-app-subscriptions before going live

Tags: ios, in-app-subscription

We have an app which is already live on the app store. We have now added in app subscriptions in it.

We want to test in app subscriptions on production mode before sending this version to the app store. Is there any solution so we can test real in app purchases in production mode not in sandbox because in sandbox testing, our client is not satisfied he is telling that we have to test it in real scenario (production mode) before going live. His point of concern is that if we go live only testing in app subscriptions through sand box then we would be facing issue in, in-app subscriptions.

Is there any way or work around to test apple in app subscriptions in production mode before going live?

Thanks

Comment: Test it on TestFlight, this runs in production mode

Comment: @Scriptable no on testflight in app subscriptions are running in sandbox mode.

Comment: "Is there any way or work around to test apple in app subscriptions in production mode before going live" No. TestFlight is as close as you can come.